# Show all products with layered navigation Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, layered-navigation, product-collection, product-grid

Now, to be able to show all the products, I have to make 1 main parent category to contain all the product category, but I think it's not the right thing to do.

Is there a page to show all the products in Magento 2 with layered navigation, or is there a block to load all products in magento 2 including the layered navigation so I can insert it in custom page?